# Mac Lane's Coherence Theorem: Why not just use the functors themselves?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I have a softball question on Mac Lane's proof.

Suppose $B=\left ( B, \square , \alpha ,\rho ,\lambda  \right )$ is a monoidal category. Fix $b\in B$. Define $W$, the (monoidal) category of binary words built recursively on the symbols $e_{0, }\left ( - \right ) $ and $ \square $; by definition, there is only one arrow in $W$ between words of the same length and none between words of different lengths.

Then, take $G_{n}$ to be the graph whose vertices are words of length $n$ and edges are compositions of basic arrows from $u_{b}$ to $v_{b}$ in $B$, where  $u_{b}$ and $v_{b}$ are obtained by "substitution" into $u$ and $v$, resp.

One then shows that any two such arrows are actually equal. It is easy to extend this result to include instances of $\rho , \lambda$, and their derivates "boxed in" by $1$.

In this way, one obtains a (unique) morphism of monoidal categories $\phi : W \rightarrow B$; $w \mapsto w_{b}$. So, the theorem follows for all compositions of appropriate arrows, which are are compositions of the $b$ components of the natural transformations $ \alpha ,\rho ,$ and $\lambda $ and their derivates "boxed in" by $1$. By taking $B$ to be It$(B)$, and $b=I$, the identity functor on $B$, one gets the result for the appropriate arrows $u\rightarrow v$, where $u$ and $v$ are functors: $B^{n}\rightarrow B$, and $B^{m}\rightarrow B$, resp.

My question is: why not start with the functors in the first place? That is, recognize that each word in $W$ is a functor obtained by "iterating" the bifunctor $\square $. Since $ \alpha ,\rho ,$ and $\lambda $ are natural, so are any of these "boxed in" by $1$. Then the proof goes through without evaluating at $b$. Of course, one must exclude the case in which any two vertices are equal, which I guess was the reason for using $W$ in the first place.